# drawRect helper methods

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, drawrect

Is it a good practice to divide drawRect, for a several methods? For example, UIView class which should draw a pie chart, has a drawRect which call multiple helper methods(for instance for draw a label, legend, triangle etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I certainly do that.  It makes it easier to understand and if necessary easy to refactor.